# Compiling R from source with AddressSanitizer support

Tags: r, address-sanitizer

How do I compile R or R-devel from source with AddressSanitizer support?

Background: My R package calls a couple of C++ functions through Rcpp. One of them throws a heap-buffer-overflow error

```
ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x611001558228 at pc 0x7f99bd0afabf bp 0x7ffeb8c90cd0 sp 0x7ffeb8c90cc8
```

... so I was told by the CRAN team. The error only shows up when using an R version with ASAN (AddressSanitizer) support. On my own R and R-devel versions, `R CMD check --as-cran` finishes with `Status: OK`. To debug the error, I need a version of R that can reproduce it.

I am running R on arch linux (4.9.11-1-ARCH). I can install `R` through `pacman` and `R-devel` through `yaourt`. For this problem though, I think might have to install R from source, which I have never done.

[Section 4.3.3 of Writing R extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Using-Address-Sanitizer) seems to be key, but I don't understand it.

Comment: Note that as you have a heap overflow, you may get away with running under Valgrind. It'll detect heap errors just as good.

Comment: @yugr How do I do that?

Comment: `valgrind --trace-children=yes prog args`

Comment: Ok thanks, I used `R -d valgrind -e '...'`. Now it's time to actually track down the error.